# Is AjpProtocol safe to use in Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, ajp

When you select AJP/1.3 as the Connector protocol in Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7 you get org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler and org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol, respectively.

According to the documentation, AjpProtocol is the new implementation, JkCoyoteHandler is the old implementation.

I'm seeing intermittent problems with AJP where an HTTP request will return after 20 seconds with an HTTP 400 response. In my attempts to track down the cause I ran across the different AJP protocol implementations and was surprised that the old implementation was the default.

Given I need a solution for Tomcat 6 now, is trying out the new AjpProtocol relatively safe? Is it stable? Or is there a reason that Tomcat 6 still defaults to the old implementation?